# Matplotlib plotting lines even though marker='.' is specified

Tags: python, matplotlib

using Python3 (IPython notebook), I do:

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2], [2, 3], marker='.', markersize=1)
```

and I get a line instead of two points, even though I'm specifying `marker='.'`

I must be missing something, because a few days ago this wasn't a problem.

EDIT:

I know the command `plt.scatter` will do the trick. I am insisting on `plt.plot()` for various compatibility issues, and also because I am curious what was the difference between a few days ago and now (as far as I recall the code is identical). Finally, I like how `plt.plot()` gives points different colors without any additional options

Comment: `marker` sets the marker.  It doesn't mean anything about what kind of line (if any) will be drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `plt.scatter()` instead of `plt.plot()`

If you need to use `plt.plot()` you can try setting the `linestyle` argument:

```
plt.plot([1, 2], [2, 3], marker='.', markersize=1, linestyle='None')
```

Comment: I know the command plt.scatter will do the trick. I am insisting on plt.plot() for various compatibility issues, and also because I am curious what was the difference between a few days ago and now (as far as I recall the code is identical). Finally, I line how plt.plot() gives points different colors without any additional options

Comment: Sorry didn't realise you're set on using plt.plot(). Try above edit, otherwise someone smarter than me may be able to help:)

Comment: Excellent, this worked. You know, I could have sworn that linestyle='None' option was missing in the previous code, and only marker='.' did the trick. Strange. Anyway, this works. Thanks!